# how should i do a parralel.foreach on a sorted dictionary

Tags: c#-4.0, parallel.foreach

I'd like to turn the following code into a parallel.foreach

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>entry in DataGroups)
 {
   // my code goes here (its not the problem).
  }
```

The DataGroups is not edited or returned, another external list DataTotal is updated by this routine. As each DataGroup contains unique indexes, and DataTotal contains a list of all possible indexes. There is no risk of a thread wanting to write twice to the same DataTotal, as the list of DataGroups only contains unique indexes.

My problem i'm trying to write this complex data structure of a sorted dictionary of int,> int (key, and data pairs), and i am confused on how to write that inside a

```
Parallel.ForEach ( KeyValuePair entry in DataGroups =>    Doesnt work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got confused with the syntax. Enumerating dictionaries is not a special case. They are just another `IEnumerable` like any other:

```
Parallel.ForEach (DataGroups, kvp => { });
```

Comment: Yes i had syntax confusion, thought i had to write down variable types in it. Thanks !